# Running Screen from PHP and using stuff

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi

I am new to PHP and need to run a screen session & send a character using stuff. My code is as below -

Call from the PHP code

```
if (!empty($key))
{
    system("/bin/bash test.sh " . $key);
}
```

I create a screen called as arduino by below

```
/usr/bin screen -dmS arduino /dev/ttyUSB0 9600
```

Call from the script file from test.sh

```
/usr/bin screen -S arduino -X stuff "$1"$'\n'
```

Is the format using 'stuff' command right - i want to send a character like x,w,d followed by 'enter'.

I have added my user to www-data already. I have checked PHP.ini but nothing out of ordinary. My web server is Apache2 and runs on /var/www

Any suggestions please?

Comment: `/bin/bash /path/to/test.sh`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My script is getting called as I have a put an echo to test it. But my problem is unable to send the character via stuff command in the screen.